# How to use symbols in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am learning Rails from Michael Hartl's [Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code-basic_signup_tests) and I am a little confused on how a symbol works/how it is used.

Here is the code snippet from the signup page test:

```
  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end
```

My question is, should this not be `click_button :submit` with the colon(:) ?

I know that symbols are like immutable strings and cannot be assigned values like `:submit = "Create my account"` . But then what does the `let()` method do exactly?

I have a Java background and am I am little confused with the symbol concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have problems with `rspec`, not with symbols. Symbols are something between `final String` and an `enum`, in Java terms, and I believe your understanding is appropriate. This is a key question here:

> But then what does the let() method do exactly?

`let` is an `rspec` method that defines a variable to be set for every example. So, basically,

```
let(:submit) { "Create my account" }
```

(where `:submit` is a symbol) instructs `rspec` to do something like

```
submit = "Create my account"
```

(where `submit` is a variable) before each `it` block.

(This is a simplification. `submit` defined here by `let` is not actually a variable, but a method name, which returns the evaluation of the block provided in `let` on its first invocation in each example, and a cached value on each subsequent invocation within the same example. But you can treat it as if it was a read-only variable. In a way, what `let :submit { ... }` does is similar to what `attr :submit` does: they both dynamically insert methods in the current context.)

Read more about `let` [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. That really helps. I understood why that symbol was needed  by the Let method. I am not sure why someone would down-vote this answer. I will accept this in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Besides within a few hard-wired constructions like `module Foo`, `class Foo`, `def foo`, `alias foo`, `defined?{foo}`, there is no way to refer to an undefined method/variable/constant verbatim.

In occasions like `let`, a symbol or a string is used instead. `let` is not doing anything with `:submit` itself. It is defining a method named `submit`, and that spelling of the method `submit` is given by the symbol `:submit`. If the method `let` were designed to take a string like `"submit"`, then that would work equally well.